# Normal positive functional on Von Neumann algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be Von Neumann algebra.

A positive linear functional ‎$‎‎‎\varphi‎$ on $A$ ‎is ‎said ‎to ‎be ‎normal ‎if ‎for ‎any ‎self‎adjoint and increasing nets such that ‎$‎‎u_{\alpha‎}\longrightarrow u‎$‎ ‎we ‎have ‎‎$‎‎‎\varphi‎(‎‎u_{\alpha})‎\longrightarrow ‎\varphi ‎(u)‎‎$.‎

I know that if ‎the positive ‎functional ‎‎$‎‎‎\varphi‎$ ‎is ‎‎$‎‎‎\sigma$-weakly‎ ‎continuous ‎then ‎‎$‎‎‎\varphi‎$ ‎is ‎normal.‎
I ‎know ‎that ‎the ‎converse ‎holds ‎but I‎ ‎don't ‎know ‎why‎.

> Q: If‎ ‎‎$‎‎‎\varphi‎$ ‎is ‎normal then‎‎ why is $‎‎‎\varphi‎$ ‎‎$‎‎‎\sigma$‎-weakly ‎continuous?

Comment: You may look at Corollary 3.11  in Operator algebras and non-commutative topology Vol 1 written by M. Takesaki.

Comment: No.because this corollary shows that completely  additive and normal are equivalent

Comment: I need a simple proof for it